# Is a grant coupled to the table name or the table reference?

Tags: mysql, sql, migration

I have table A which is a grant of select for a specific user on an ip address. I am adding a column as PK to the table by creating a new table A_new and moving the data over and then renaming A and A_new to A_old and A respectively. When there is a `GRANT SELECT` on the *old A table*, will this be applicable to the new A table as well? Or do I have to do a new GRANT SELECT on the new table?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a new GRANT SELECT on the new table